# How to maintain list order in a new dictionary, if I want to compare it with dictionary value and replace it?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to compare list with dictionary keys and make a new dictionary if they match. The problem is that I dont know how to maintain list order.

```
   list = [cat, dog, horse, kitten]
   dict = {dog: 1, cat: 5}
   filter_dict = {}
   for key, value in dict.items():
            if key in list:
                filter_dict[key] = value
    print(filter_dict)
```

What I need:

```
filter_dict= {cat: 5, dog: 1}
```

What I get:

```
filter_dict = {dog: 1, cat: 5}
```

Comment: Older Python versions don't support an order in dictionaries, since 3.6 the order in which elements are added to a dictionary is preserved, since 3.7 this is guaranteed.

Comment: search ordereddict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a Python version later than or equal to 3.6 (dictionaries are guaranteed to maintain order), you should loop over the list when constructing your dictionary not the original dict if you wish the keys to be in the same order as in the list

Looping over the dict will always produce the keys in the same order as the original dict

```
for item in your_list:
    if item in your_dict:
        filter_dict[item] = your_dict[item]
```

This can be achieved with a comprehension

```
filter_dict = {key: your_dict[key] for key in your_list if key in your_dict}
```